# how to create button group component in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to create button-group component in vue using typescript:

```
      <template>
    <slot>
      <CButton
        v-for="(vnode, index) in $slots.default || []"
        :key="index"
        :class="[
          { 'first-index': index === 0 },
          { 'last-index': index === ($slots.default ? $slots.default.length : 0) - 1 },
        ]"
      >
        {{ index }}
        {{ vnode }}
      </CButton>
    </slot>
  </div>
    </template>
```

Here index comes null but I am expecting it turns as much as button I added.

Here is the parent:

```
<ButtonGroup>
      <CustomButton>1</CustomButton>
      <CustomButton>2</CustomButton>
      <CustomButton>3</CustomButton>
    </ButtonGroup>
```

Comment: You don't need to fill the `<slot>` component, this is the place for the default template the slot has when it's not used. So you should already have your CustomButton in your slot, and the `v-for` is not used :)

Comment: I changed my component as it is now in the question but this time nothing to display

Comment: You just need to add `<slot>` in your ButtonGroup component, nothing else. You don't need to use `$slots.default`

Comment: the reason why I am using index is to add class according to that, please have a look updated question.

Comment: You won't have `$slots.default` defined if you don't have a `<slot>` component inside. You need a custom class on the CustomButton? Just add it from the consumer component, not within the ButtonGroup component.

Comment: I really dont understand. Can you write a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you need to use slots in Vue:

```html
<!-- ButtonGroup -->
<template>
  <div class="button-group">
    <slot></slot> <!-- Define the default slot -->
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<template>
  <ButtonGroup>
    <!-- Fill in the slot with whatever you want -->
    <CustomButton class="my-class">Test</CustomButton>
    <button class="regular-button">Normal</button>
    <CustomButton />
  </div>
</template>
```

Example [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)